# join produces wrong results though the joining columns are of same datatype. Right results are after casting them to different datatype

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have an interesting problem to find the root cause.
Inner join 2 tables on 2 columns, but the results are not expected. The data types for both columns are the same in both tables. Here is the test code with sample data.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products
(
    prod_id BIGINT NOT NULL
    ,prod_no INTEGER NOT NULL
    ,prod_name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
    ,eff_start_dt TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
    ,lob VARCHAR(100)
    ,market VARCHAR(100)
)
DISTSTYLE KEY
 DISTKEY (prod_id)
 SORTKEY (prod_id, prod_no, lob, market)
;

/*
prod_id  | prod_no  | prod_name  | eff_start_dt  | lob     | market |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
123      | 3        | 'abcd'     | 9/13/21       | 'Sales' | 'US'   |
*/


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products_sales
(
    prod_id BIGINT NOT NULL
    ,prod_no INTEGER NOT NULL
    ,sales_team VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
    ,eff_dt TIMESTAMP NOT null
    ,cust_typ VARCHAR(15)
)
DISTSTYLE KEY
 DISTKEY (prod_id)
 SORTKEY (prod_id, prod_no)
;

/*
prod_id  | prod_no  | sales_team  | eff_dt  | cust_typ
------------------------------------------------------
123      | 3        | 'CustServ'  | 12/1/21 | 'Ent'
123      | 3        | 'Marketing' | 11/5/21 | 'Ent'
*/


select tab1.prod_id, tab1.prod_no, tab1.lob, tab2.sales_team
from products tab1 
inner join products_sales tab2
on tab1.prod_id = tab2.prod_id
and tab1.prod_no = tab2.prod_no
where tab2.cust_typ = 'Ent'
and tab1.prod_id = 123
and tab1.prod_no = 3;

/* Results: only 1 row
prod_id  | prod_no  | eff_dt  | sales_team
-------------------------------------------
123      | 3        | 12/1/21 | 'CustServ'
*/

/* Expected Results: 2 rows
prod_id  | prod_no  | eff_dt  | sales_team
-------------------------------------------
123      | 3        | 12/1/21 | 'CustServ'
123      | 3        | 11/5/21 | 'Marketing'
*/
```

I can achieve the accurate results in many other ways, listed below:

- If I change the inner join to the left join, it produces accurate results.
- If I explicitly cast the second column `prod_no` in the join condition to another datatype, it produces an accurate result.  `and cast(tab1.prod_no as bigint) = tab2.prod_no`
- If I create a temporary table with just the table join (with no filter) and then query the temporary table with filters, I get the accurate result.
- If I create another set of these tables and copy the data to the new tables and if I run the same query on new tables, it produces accurate results but existing tables don't.

Here I'm looking for help to find the root cause of this problem in Redshift. Any expert guidance or any lead is highly appreciated!

Comment: Any primary key or unique constraints on the tables?

Comment: Your life and code will be simpler if you use consistent data types

Answer (score 0):

The below SQL runs fine on my Redshift.  There was an error in your provided code so I expect that you reduce your issue to this test case. I still strongly suspect a PK or Unique constraint that Redshift doesn't enforce.  If you are still having issues please provide a demonstration of the issue and/or more information about when this issue occurs.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products
(
    prod_id BIGINT NOT NULL
    ,prod_no INTEGER NOT NULL
    ,prod_name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
    ,eff_start_dt TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
    ,lob VARCHAR(100)
    ,market VARCHAR(100)
)
DISTSTYLE KEY
DISTKEY (prod_id)
SORTKEY (prod_id, prod_no, lob, market)
;

insert into products values
(123, 3, 'abcd', '2021/9/13 00:00:00', 'Sales', 'US' );

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products_sales
(
    prod_id BIGINT NOT NULL
    ,prod_no INTEGER NOT NULL
    ,sales_team VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
    ,eff_dt TIMESTAMP NOT null
    ,cust_type VARCHAR(15)  
)
DISTSTYLE KEY
DISTKEY (prod_id)
SORTKEY (prod_id, prod_no)
;

insert into products_sales values
(123, 3, 'CustServ', '2021/12/1 00:00:00', 'Ent'),
(123, 3, 'Marketing', '2021/11/5 00:00:00', 'Ent');

select tab1.prod_id, tab1.prod_no, tab1.lob, tab2.sales_team
from products tab1 
inner join products_sales tab2
on tab1.prod_id = tab2.prod_id
and tab1.prod_no = tab2.prod_no
where tab2.cust_type = 'Ent'
and tab1.prod_id = 123
and tab1.prod_no = 3;
```

Comment: Thank you @Bill for taking the time to review. 
There is no PK or Unique constraint defined on those tables.
I corrected the typo on one column name in my original post.

I still have the same problem. I'm not looking for a correction in my SQL code. I know, it is fine and will produce the right result if create these tables again and run the same SQL code. Since these tables are existing ones and the right SQL code produces the wrong results, I'm looking for a clue for the possible root cause. I'm somehow suspecting the DistKey/SortKey but don't know how they work internally.

Comment: Does the code I posted produce the correct results for you?  I suspect it will.  So what I'm missing is what is different about my test code and your situation.  If not due to an erroneous uniqueness constraint then it is something else.  I there some definition missing from my test data?  The  code?  Unlikely that the dist and sort keys are the root cause but never say never.  They just control how the data is organized on disk.  My only other idea at the moment is that the metadata became corrupt but I've never seen that before.  Does the error change after ANALYZE?

Comment: I tried ANALYZE as well but no difference. I have never seen this before myself. I have been working on different databases for more than 13 years. 
Your code works fine but if I replace the tables from the select statement with my real tables, the results are the same (partial).

Comment: Code works but not with your data.  This is why I thought of a uniqueness constraint (UNIQUE, PK, FK).  Redshift doesn't enforce these but uses them to optimize query execution.  So if not uniqueness then ...  I'll ponder

Comment: I only see 3 possibilities - 1) Redshift has bug, 2) Some data has been corrupted, 3) the data / data model has some issue leading to the behavior.  A bug is always a possibility but RS has many hours of use so this is very unlikely.  The other 2 options require rely on data "issues".  If you copy the table to another table with the same DDL does the issue remain?  Can you recreate the issue if you only use a subset of the original tables data?  When you copy the table's DDL pull from RS using https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminViews/v_generate_tbl_ddl.sql